# A problem about the measure of a curve.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $T$ is a curve $y=f(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ where $f$ is continuous. Show that $m(T)=0$.

I don't understand it i even cant understand why "$f$ is continuous" is necessary.

Please tell me about the importance of that condition and then prove the claim.

Comment: That is not true. [Space filling curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) exist.

Comment: this is true if you restrict $f$ to a bounded box, say $Q$.

Comment: @Student The $y = f(x)$ probably means that the curve shall be the graph of a continuous function. Why it wasn't put thus is beyond me, however.

Answer (score 0):

I will do the problem assuming $f$ is restricted to a closed interval $A$. Say $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$. Let

$$ \Gamma_f = \{ (x,y) : y = f(x) \} $$

I want to show that $\Gamma_f$ has measure zero. To this end, let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Since $f$ is continuous on $A$, then $f$ is integrable on $A$. In particular, we can take a partition $P$ such that

$$ \sum_{I } \left( \sup_{x \in I} f(x) - \inf_{x \in I} f(x) \right)  |I| = U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \epsilon $$

where $I$ is a subinterval determined by the partition $P$. Since $\inf_{I} f \leq f \leq \sup_{I} f $, then we see that $\Gamma_f \subseteq ( \inf_I f, \sup_I f ) \times I = \mathcal{K}$. In particular, $\mathcal{K}$ is cover for $\Gamma_f$. Furthermore,

$$ Vol( \mathcal{K} ) = \left( \sup_{x \in I} f(x) - \inf_{x \in I} f(x) \right)  |I| $$

summing over all the subrectangles $I$, we get our result.

Answer (score 0):

Fact. The graph $\Gamma_f$ of an arbitrary measurable function $f:R \to R$ is of $m$-measure zero, where $m$ denotes two-dimensional Lebesgue measure in $R^2$.

Proof. Notice that $\Gamma_f$ is measurable subset of $R^2$. Here theoretically two cases are
possible: a) $m( \Gamma_f)>0$ or b) $m( \Gamma_f)=0$; Case a) is not mossible. Indeed, consider  $ \Gamma_f+\alpha \times (0.1)$ for $\alpha \in R$. From invariance of the $m$, we deduce that  this is a family of pairwise disjoint measurable subsets with equal positive $m$-measures. Since its cardinality is $c$, we  get contradiction with the $\sigma$-finiteness property of $\mu$. Hence there is possible only case b).